# SQL Server Multiple Cascade Path Issue, instead of triggers, how can I change my tables?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

tbl_Company

```
CompanyID int PK
CreatedBy int 
PrimaryOwner int
```

and

tbl_Users

```
UserID int PK
etc.
```

I'm using a CMS and don't want to alter internal procedures and functions related to the CMS, such as when a user is deleted, but I want t he first table, tbl_Company (CreatedBy and PrimaryOwner) to revert to NULL if a user is ever permanently deleted, allowing an administrator to handle it from there, as in reassign the company to someone else.

I'm trying to reinforce data-integrity with FK restraints. The UserID From the Users table is related to both mentioned fields in the Company table.

But if I allow NULLS on both CreatedBy and PrimaryOwner, and try to SET NULL in Delete Rule, I get the error:

**may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths**

I've found several threads on this, some saying to use triggers, others to manually map out the delete procedures, but I can't do this.

Is there a solid way to get around this that I'm missing? I'm considering breaking the primary owner into another table, but wanted to avoid it, as there can always only be a single primary owner.

Comment: Audit columns like that are one place where denormalizing is very common. Instead of storing the primary key from the Users table you could store their Username as varchar. This way when a user is deleted you can still tell "whodunnit". If you are deadset on keeping this fully normalized and using foreign keys you would probably have to do this in a trigger. The real downside there is that you lose information when a user is deleted. That is the hidden cost of normalization for auditing.